# RTL8188CUS module for Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: wireless, realtek

I had this chipset working under 13.04 but under 13.10 it fails after a few minutes.

The device is an Edimax EW7811un and the RTL8188CUS was reported from lsusb in 13.04 and 13.10.

Realtek don't seem to suport this beyond Linux Kernel 2.6.18~3.9

Comment: PLease show the ouput of `lspci` and if is there is output of `ifconfig -a`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This chipset still has problems for recent kernel updates for both 13.04 and 13.10 that have been reported and kernel maintainers are aware of them.

The main discussion is here [Bug #1244408](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1244408) is here, from where I found a temporary solution, from somebody that updated a patch.

Realtek has provided the driver for older versions of Linux kernel, lower then 3.9 included, as 3.10 should include it and should work out of the box.

You can use this patch [8192cu fixes](https://github.com/pvaret/rtl8192cu-fixes) that will make it stable, or wait for this fix to be included as it was accepted and committed, so it will be on one of the next kernel update I guess.

If you connect to only a few personal access points, you can configure them only on B/G as the problem is only for N. I have 2 access points in my house and I have a stable connection on the one with B/G only.